# Tiagra 4703 74mm bcd, 4 bolt small chainring

Tags: chainring

I have search the internet but to no avail to try and find a 74mm bcd 28t or 26t inner chainring with 4 bolts.

Does such a thing exist?

The nearest I can find it this but I want less than 30t:

http://picclick.co.uk/SHIMANO-FC4703-TIAGRA-10-SPEED-74mm-BCD-4-262545355186.html
[image]

Comment: A 74 mm bcd constrains you to a minimum of 24 teeth, so it should be theoretically possible (but maybe not financially feasible -- the audience is essentially just new Shimano triple owners). The other option is to switch the crank to a 5 bolt where such rings are easy to find.

Comment: Ok where do I find the 4 bolt 74mm chainring?

Answer (score 4):

I've scoured some distributors and I don't think this exists. There's really only a couple 4-bolt asymmetrical triples out there period, and they haven't been out very long. I don't think you're going to see this anytime soon either, because it would blow past the RD max capacity specs of the applicable groups, which is a non-starter from a manufacturer's perspective. Sadly, these are not the cranks to own if you want freedom to customize your gearing, which is pretty ironic since conventional 110/74 are some of the best of all time for it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Nathan. So looks like I need get a 5 bolt triple for the front. Would it be best to go down the tiagra 5 arm route? Would previous models be compatible with my tiagra front mech etc?

Comment: It depends on what gearing you want, but if the 39 and 50 are staying then any of the 5-bolt 30/39/50 10-speed Shimano triples would be fine. Of note is that you're bypassing Shimano's total capacity spec to do this, and there's several caveats. First is the FD may not physically be able to reach down that far. Usually this isn't the limiting factor but I haven't done it with FD-4703 yet. Second is you'll be limited on what small/small combinations you can use without cage rub. Third is that shifting performance can be marginal, and you may need to add a chain catcher to prevent chain drop.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. What do you mean by "shifting performance can be marginal"? What is a chain catcher. How will I know if I need one?

Comment: STI/front indexing in general, and for road triples in particular, are pretty reliant on their ramping, FD cage profiling, and tooth profiling all working in unison for shifting to be as smooth and consistent as intended. It tends to still be workable, but the results are a little unpredictable. A chain catcher is a plastic piece that clamps to your seat tube that prevents the chain from being able to fall off the inner ring. They let the inner limit be a bit further out, which can be useful here. I put them on preemptively when doing this, but you need it if your chain is dropping.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. So would you advise I go down the Tiagra 5 bolt route then bearing in mind the shifting issues? I hope to put a 26t on.

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is kind of eyeball up where the chain is contacting the cage on the existing FD when shifting out of the 30. Does the FD have much room to give below that point? If so then it's a fine and probably fairly economical choice IF you're fine staying with the 39/50 rings forever and also if you're okay that it's always a little bit of an experiment to do this. If you're not both of those things, or if you might want smaller mid and big rings at some point, then I would look at getting a 110/74 crank. I don't have any go-to ones to recommend for 10 speed though.

Comment: Hi Nathan - I've looked the FD cage when in gear 30 (front) and 34 (rear) and I estimate well over 10mm chain clearance (vertical) for the chain. I've put it in gear 30 (front) and 23 (rear) and it is about 5mm. Therefore I think if I reduced the front gear to a 26t it should work? I am happy with the 50/39 front option. Just want to adjust the small ring to 26. I have a Shimano BB-RS500 BB Cups (Tiagra 4700) bottom bracket. I assume any Shimano Hollowtech II triple chainset will work with this? Any recommendations?

Comment: Yeah, that all seems worth a shot then. All Shimano road cranks will go in their road bottom brackets, so that part is a go.